# Setting Pi as colorbar tick with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, ticks

I am trying to set the colorbar ticks as -pi and pi. Is this possible within the colorbar style settings? This is what I have tried so far but it doesn't work.

```
colorbar style={
    %at={(0,1.0)},               % <-- (changed)
    anchor=below south west,    % <-- (changed)
    % change the width of the colorbar relative to the main `axis' environment
    height=0.05*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height},
    width=1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis width},
    xtick={$-\pi$,$\pi$},
    at={(0,-0.25)},%anchor=south west
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX. The `xtick` key is for setting the x-values where you get ticks, and `$\pi$` isn't a value, it is a mathematical symbol. To set the text shown at those ticks, you use `xticklabels={..}`.

So what you want is probably

```
xtick={-pi,pi},
xticklabels={$-\pi$,$\pi$}
```

in the `colorbar style`.

Using `pi` works in `xtick` because (I presume) the values are parsed by the `pgf` math engine, where `pi` is recognized as a keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! This worked for me in the end:

```
colorbar style={
    anchor=below south west,
    xtick={0,1},
    xticklabels={\strut$-\pi$,\strut$\pi$},
    height=0.05*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis height},
    width=1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/parent axis width},
    at={(0,-0.31)}
}
```

I had to add the values 0 and 1 for the xtick. Also I have used `\strut` so that the `$\pi$` keeps aligned with `$-\pi$`